# Why am I getting Timeout Error instead of element not present?

Tags: ruby, rspec, selenium-webdriver, timeoutexception, page-object-gem

I'm testing a web application using page-object gem with selenium Webdriver.

In the home page [Start page] I have a few RSpec verifications. But I'm getting the following error instead of the RSpec exception:

```
>Timeout::Error (Timeout::Error)
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:146:in `rescue in rbuf_fill'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:140:in `rbuf_fill'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:122:in `readuntil'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:132:in `readline'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:2562:in `read_status_line'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:2551:in `read_new'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1319:in `block in transport_request'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1316:in `catch'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1316:in `transport_request'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1293:in `request'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1286:in `block in request'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:745:in `start'
```

Does anyone facing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with ruby, and without the code it is hard to answer. But here comes my guess:

Selenium uses the concept of [explicit and implicit waits](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp) when you try to access a DOM element. So I guess that you use some sort of selector on the element in question and then selenium tries to find it. It seems to be not present and as a result the Timeout is thrown. The behavior is expected.

Comment: If the element is not present in the page I should get appropriate error message. [element not present]This error message is something strange for me.

Comment: Well, maybe I am wrong, but you did not show the relevant code parts, so all I can do is guessing.

Comment: class StartPage
  include PageObject
  page_url "#{URL}"
  link    :login,   :link => "Sign IN"
   expected_element :login
 end

This is the start page code. I'm getting the error in the expected element line. It supposed to throw element not present. but I'm getting Timeout error.